# How can Python do string substitution without %s?

Tags: python, sql, string

Check out the following lines of Python 2.6 code I found:

```
key = 'hire_date' 
update_dict['key'] = update_dict[key]     #added e.g. {..., 'key': '12/31/1999'}
if key == 'hire_date':
     query_string = "UPDATE employee SET " + key + "= CAST(%(key)s AS DATE) WHERE emp_id = '" + emp.employee + "'"
```

I've tested this code, and it works. It successfully updates the employee's hire_date field in the database to whatever date `'key'`'s value in the dictionary is.

I was in the middle of parameterizing it when I noticed the `%(key)s` somehow manages to get the value of the dictionary at `'key'`. How does it do that? I always thought you had to add `% dictionaryOrTupleOrWhatever` after the string for this to work.

Comment: I think you missed an interpolation somewhere; the code you posted only concatenates.

Comment: The effect you are seeing is not from the python code, it's the SQL query that's exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: Martijn, you're right; the interpolation happens later with an `execute(query_string, update_dict)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you'll find later in the code that there is a DB API `execute` statement that takes `update_dict` as a parameter.  The DB API then does the substitution instead of Python string formatting and thus properly handles binding.

Have a look at this: http://furius.ca/pubcode/pub/antiorm/lib/python/dbapiext.html#escaping-in-the-dbapi-2-0

Comment: You're right about the execute statement using `update_dict` as a parameter, and I completely missed that. Is it better to do parameterization in the application, or letting the DB handle it? Or is it all preference?

Comment: Definitely let DB API do the binding; you'll avoid SQL injections that way since you rely on the library to do string escapes and the like.

Comment: Does interpolating with Python not prevent any SQL injecting? Or is it just not as bulletproof?

Comment: Python string formatting does no parameter escaping whatsoever.  Try `"select name from emp where name = '%s'" % "foo'; drop table emp"` for an example.

Answer (score 3):

In the code that you pasted, no interpolation takes place.  However, the variable could later be interpolated:

```
>>> x = "%(var)s" # no interpolation yet
>>> d = {'var': 88}
>>> x % d # interpolate into the stored string
'88'
```

Given that the code you posted looks like SQL, it could also be interpolated later via an SQL library call.  Many SQL interface libraries provide a similar sort of string-substitution using `%` signs and encourage users to use these rather than the built-in string substitution, since the SQL library versions have various safeguards to prevent malicious injection attacks.